# Validate multiple checked listboxes for at least 1 checked item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 18 checked listboxes on my Windows form and I want to make sure that at least one item is checked by the user.

```
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count < 0)
{
    Messagebox.Show("check atleast one item");
}
........
if (checkedListBox18.CheckedIndices.Count < 0)
{
    Messagebox.Show("check atleast one item");
}
```

I want to know what the easiest way to do this is, rather than writing multiple if's for all the 18 checked listboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show messagebox only once, try the following:

```
CheckedListBox[] controls = new[]{control1, control2,...};

if (controls.Any(x=> x.CheckedIndices.Count <= 0))
{
    Messagebox.Show("check atleast one item");
}
```

Otherwise try the following(though it doesn't makes sense for me)

```
foreach(var control in controls)
{
    if(control.CheckedIndices.Count <= 0)
    {
        Messagebox.Show("check atleast one item");
    }
}
```

Also consider providing some hint to the user about what to select. For everything you're saying "check atleast one item", How would the user know which one he missed?